# Cloth simulation workflow

Tags: cloth-simulation

I’m making my first project with Blender and it’s special effects for a film project. I would need to animate a cloth with a cloth simulation. It’s just a plane that tries to imitate house curtains as I’m trying to make curtains move in a weird way.
I have a plane with dimensions 5m x 14m (measurements of the real curtains), and that will be made into cloth and then manipulated with various collision objects.

I have two separate questions on this:

1. video reference.
   I need to sync the animation to filmed footage, so I have imported the film clip as image plane. To use as a reference. Is this the correct way to use reference video? It seems to mess up the cloth simulation in 2.8 and I need to remove it before baking…
2. baking
   I’m trying to mach the cloth properties to the filmed real cloth. That means tweaking a lot of the cloth properties in order to get right mass, bending etc.
   The problem is that the baking of the cloth physics takes a lot of time. For every little tweak I need to bake the physics again which takes 15-30minutes… so it makes this extremely tedious work. Is there a better way to do this?

I’m aware there’s the surface deform modifier, but as I’m trying to mach filmed footage, I find it quite complex way of getting exact results.. or would it be the best way to do this?

How would you do this?

My setup is Ryzen 7 2700x and RTX2070. Blender 2.8

Thank you!!